# How do you graph $x^2 - 6x + y^2 + 2y + 6 = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you find the graph of the equation $x^2 - 6x + y^2 + 2y + 6 = 0$?

Comment: hint: complete the squares. this represents a circle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complete the squares to find the center and radius of the circle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911609/complete-the-squares-to-find-the-center-and-radius-of-the-circle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to reduce the LHS into a perfect square.

$$x^2- 6x = x^2 - 6x + 9 - 9 = (x-3)^2 - 9$$

$$y^2 + 2y + 6 = y^2 + 2y + 1 + 5 = (y+ 1)^2 + 5$$

After putting these back in the equation, and re-arranging, you'll have the form:

$$(x-a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = r^2$$

This is a circle of center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$.

Answer (score 1):

The left hand side of the equation can be simplified by completing the square.
$$x^2-6x+y^2+2y+6 $$ $$=x^2-6x+9-9+y^2+2y+1-1+6=0$$

Because $x^2-6x+9 = (x-3)^2$ and $y^2+2y+1 = (y+1)^2$ we obtain:
$$=(x-3)^2-9+(y+1)^2-1+6=0$$
$$\implies(x-3)^2 +(y+1)^2 -4 = 0$$
$$\implies(x-3)^2 +(y+1)^2 = 4 $$ 
The equation of a circle with center at the point $(h, k)$ and radius $r$ is:
$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2 = r^2$$
Comparing these equations we get that the center of the circle is $(3,-1)$ and the radius is $2$ and this is very easy to graph.